# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS using blocks

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access, skaction

I have subclassed SKSpriteNode for my enemies. One of the methods in this class is a "blood squirt" `SKAction` sequence comprised of blocks which takes about 0.9 secs to complete.

```
-(void)runBloodBurst
{
    SKSpriteNode *bloodBurst = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[_animations bloodBurstLeft2Start]];
    bloodBurst.zPosition = 250;
    bloodBurst.position = CGPointMake(-32, 0);

    SKAction *wait0 = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.2];

    SKAction *wait1 = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.7];

    SKAction *block0 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [bloodBurst runAction:[_animations bloodBurstLeft2]];
        [self addChild:bloodBurst];
    }];

    SKAction *block1 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [bloodBurst removeFromParent];
        self.readyBloodBurst2 = true;
    }];

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait0, block0, wait1, block1]]];
}
```

If the player is attacking very enthusiastically, the blood squirt method could be called again before the 0.9 secs have passed (numerous blood squirts). However, this would randomly throw a `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

My solution was use a `BOOL` ivar to not allow running the sequence again until it has completed. This stopped the `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` but I do not understand the root cause behind it.

An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As per LearnCocos2D request, added exception breakpoint and got this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does [_animations bloodBurstLeft2] do?

Comment: @0x141E - It's a SKAction animateWithTextures:

Comment: I copied your code, added my own animateWithTextures SKAction, and called runBloodBurst in a loop 100 times with no delay. It worked fine in both Xcode 5 and 6.

Comment: add exception breakpoint, you need to post the exact line and call stack of the crash

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - done and posted.

Comment: Is your update method in SKCSprite calling itself?

Comment: @0x141E - I don't understand what you mean. The enemy class' update method is called by the scene's update. The above code is only triggered by scene's didBeginContact:

Comment: Where's the definition of `_animations bloodBurstLeft2` ?

Comment: tried it with my iOS8/XCode6 beta with the above code, an no ivar and I get no error. Differences were that I don't have the definition for your `SKActions` for your bloodBurstLeft2 animation. I got no crashes and was repeatedly calling the `runBloodBurst` method as fast as I could. (tap triggered)  So simply not calling it again before the last has completed, is not the issue in my opinion.

Comment: If you want to github the project, I'd take a look at it, but I'm pretty sure there's factors outside this limited code. Seeing where `_animations` defines animations via `SKAction` would be helpful.

Comment: The stack trace looks like SKCSprite's update method is calling itself or possibly the update method of another instance of SKCSprite. It would be helpful if you posted the code for SKCSprite's update method. Also, have you ever used NSZombie?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @0x141E - not yet. Going to do up a sample project with all the relevant code as soon as I get back from vacation :)